# How do you post data in django with attribute depth=1 in the serializer?

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have a django model called “Enrolment” that depends on two other models through foreign key.  “Course” model and “Enrolment” model. The “Course” model is like so:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    prerequisite = models.TextField(blank=True)
    fee = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the Enrolment model is like so:

```
class CourseEnrolment(models.Model):
    
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Course, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    schedule = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        UserAccount, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    enrolment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name.name
```

For me to gain access to the information about the enrolled course, I have to do like so in the CourseEnrolmentSerializer:

```
class CourseEnrolmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseEnrolment
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
```

With “depth = 1” being the secret to accessing information about the course. Now when I fetch enrolment, I get a response like below, which is exactly what I want like so.

```
 {
        "id": 5
        "schedule": "June 23, 2022",
        "course_name": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "fundamentals-of-programming",
            "description": "some description .",
            "prerequisite": "some prerequisite",
            "fee": 1000,
     },
        "student": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "martinsakinbo@yahoo.com",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "phone": "1111111",
        }
    },
```

Now, the problem I have is that with “depth=1” in the serializer, I’m not able to create an enrolment when I write the following view

```
class CourseEnrolment(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = CourseEnrolment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseEnrolmentSerializer
```

Trying to create enrolment in postman by doing like so:

```
{
        "course_name": 3,
        "schedule": "June 23, 2022",
        "student": 1
}
```

Generates the error the “null value in column "course_name_id" of relation "course_courseenrolment" violates not-null constraint”
I equally tried by nesting into the course_name id and student id by doing like so:

```
{
        "course_name.id": 3,
        "schedule": "June 23, 2022",
        "student.id": 1
}
```

I get the same error.
But if I remove depth=1 from the serializer, everything works, and I’m about to create an enrolment
PLEASE HOW DO I CREATE (POST) AN ENROLMENT STILL WITH “depth=1”? OR IS THERE A BETTER OR DIFFERENT WAY I SHOULD WRITE MY VIEW. IF YES, HOW?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new serializer specific for creating course enrollment:

```
class CreateCourseEnrollmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = CourseEnrolment
       fields = "__all__"
```

And inside the view define `get_serializer_class()` method in the following way (which you may want to use if your view supports more the one HTTP action. Actions are available to `rest_framework.viewsets`):

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import CreateCourseEnrollmentSerializer, CourseEnrolmentSerializer

class CourseEnrollmentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return CreateCourseEnrollmentSerializer
        return CourseEnrolmentSerializer
```

And in the app's `urls.py`:

```
from .views import CourseEnrollmentView

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"course-enrollments", CourseEnrollmentView)

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: self.action? I'm not aware of such attribute. Also, is there any http method called "create"? I know there is a generics override method called "perform_create"

Comment: I tried your code and got 'CreateEnrollmentView' object has no attribute 'action'

Comment: Sorry, my bad. 'action' attribute is not available to generic views, it's available to viewsets however. I'll update my answer.

Comment: DRF provides actions as an alternative to HTTP methods. In HTTP we have the common ones (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE). For actions we have (create, list, retrieve, update, partial_update, destroy). both list and retrieve are GET method. However, list is used to query more than one object, while retrieve is used to get one object.

Comment: Yeah. Well, I solved the problem by creating a new serializer class. Though I didn't have to  define any override method. I Knew creating another serializer will most likely solve the problem, but I was concerned about having multiple serializer for such task. Though  the problem is solved, I'm still curious about getting an approach that will not involve creating another serializer

Comment: @Mart I'm not sure if this is the effect you want, but you can write in `CourseEnrolmentSerializer` the following: `course_name = CourseSerializer(read_only=True)`. This way you won't need depth=1 and you won't have to submit data related to the `Course` model.